# Matching the number of occurrences of a 3D list with a reference list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, compare

I'm working on a problem, but I hit a roadblock and I was hoping you can help me, so basically I have a 3D list of coordinates and I'm comparing to another 3D list of coordinates that I use for reference. What I'm trying to do is count the number of occurrences of the coordinates and match the occurrences with the reference list. For that, I transform the `coordinates list` to `tuples` and then I use `Counter` to count the number of occurrences, what I need is match the `key` found in `Count` with coordinates in the `reference list` and stored the `values` in a list of lists.   Maybe the code will explain better than me. Here is my code

```
from collections import Counter

reference = [[[2, 3], [3, 2], [3, 4], [4, 3]], 
             [[2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 2], [4, 2]],  #3D References list with all the coordinates.
             [[2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 2], [4, 2]]]

coordinates =   [[[3, 2]], [[3, 2], [2, 4], [2, 4]], [[2, 4]]] #List to match the reference list

newlist = [[tuple(j) for j in i] for i in coordinates] #Transform the coordinates list to tuple to use Counter

aux = []
for i in newlist:
    aux.append(Counter(i))          #Count the number of occurrences.
print(aux)

#aux = [Counter({(3, 2): 1}), Counter({(2, 4): 2, (3, 2): 1}), Counter({(2, 4): 1})

a = [list(i.values()) for i in aux] #Getting only the values of occurrence.

print(a)     #a = [[1], [1, 2], [1]]
```

The first Counter in the `aux list` have only the key `(3, 2)` with 1 occurrence  so I need to match the `key` with the coordinates on the first list of the  `reference list`, as you can see in the first Counter there are some missing `keys` (coordinates) comparing to the other list, so I need those missing coordinates have the value of zero. The Second Counter have two keys  `(2, 4), (3, 2)` with the corresponding values of 2 and 1, comparing to the second list of the `reference list` there is also some missing coordinates, so they will have the value of zero and so on. This is my desired output:

```
#Output
a = [[0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 2, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0]
```

There is some way I can do this? "Fill" the missing coordinates with a value of zero? If you can point me to the right direction that would be great and sorry for my terrible english!. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just navigate through each coordinate from `reference` and check the number of counts of that coordinate in corresponding counter in `aux`

```
aux = [Counter(tuple(j) for j in i) for i in coordinates]
a = [[cntr[tuple(j)] for j in i] for i,cntr in zip(reference,aux)]
print (a)
# [[0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 2, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but I got another question similar to this, if you have time, can you check it up?